# Limiting large numbers

Tags: javascript

Simple question, how do I go about limiting a large number so it stays between 0-100. For Example:

8976382 would convert too 89

My attempt:

```
Math.min(Math.max(8976382, 1), 100)
```

Comment: Whence is the source of your large numbers?

Comment: it would depend on the type of mapping you want from one space to another. Is it uniform, asymptotic or something else, for example.

Comment: `8976382 % 100` seems to work quite well. Is there any problems doing it that way?

Comment: @Shivam, that will give the the _final_ two digits (e.g., `82`) rather than the _first_ two (e.g., `89`).

Comment: `("" + 8976382).substr(0,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have (the `min/max` method) isn't going to convert `8976382` into `89`, but into `100` instead.

A simple algorithm (for positive numbers anyway, and assuming the upper end of the range is exclusive, so it's `0..99` inclusive) would be:

```
while num >= 100:
    num = int(num / 10)
```

That should be easily convertible into *any* procedural language, such as the Javascript:

```
var num = 8976382;
while (num >= 100) {
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
}
alert(num);
```

which gives you `89` as requested.

Another option is to use the substring operation to grab the first (up to) two characters.

```
var num = 8976382;
num = ("" + num).substr(0,2);
alert(num);
```

If the range you want is actually `0..100` inclusive at *both* ends, use `>` rather than `>=` in the first solution. In that case, the substring method becomes problematic since you have to detect strings starting with `100` specially.

Comment: I think this solution is the better one.

Comment: You could also do `int(num / Math.pow(10, 2))`. I'm not sure why you would need the while loop.

Comment: @Asad, apply that expression to `8976382` and it gives you `89763`, not _really_ between zero and a hundred. The idea of the `while` loop is to keep reducing the number until you get `100` or below.

Comment: Seems like OP just need first two digits which he/she can get through trimming. something like this: `("" + 8976382).substr(0,2)`.

Comment: @Mr_Green, that should be an _answer_ rather than a comment. That way, the best answer will hopefully rise to the top (the way SO is meant to work). I'll add that as another option but, if you want to make your comment an answer, let me know and I'll revert the change.

Comment: Just a note... these two solutions will have different outcomes for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
+(8976382 + "").slice(0,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just need first two digits of a number (*excluding 100*). If that is so, then you can get those first two digits using `substr` or other javascript string manipulating methods like `substring`.

```
var num = 8976382;
var result = ("" + num).substr(0,2);

// Output => "89"
```

This works even if you have only one digit. Say:

```
var num = 3;
var result = ("" + 3).substr(0, 2);

// Output => "3"
```

Later if you want to convert that output string to number, use `parseInt` or just add `+` to the above code:

```
var num = 8976382;
var result = +("" + 8976382).substr(0,2);

// Output => 89
```

NOTE: If there is a possibility for negative numbers then consider adding condition as `if( num > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 8976382;
y = parseInt((x+'').slice(0,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the first two digits of a number when that number is greater than 100.

So I would do it like this in Javascript:

```
var y = 8976382;
var x = y < 100 ? y : parseInt((''+y).substring(0, 2));
```

And like this in Java:

```
int y = 8976382;
int x = y < 100 ? y : Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(y).substring(0, 2));
```