# Changing numbers to percentage from an array

Tags: javascript

I want change my the numbers in a array to percentages but im not sure how to go about doing this.

```
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];
```

should be:

```
var results = [84, 78, 65, 58, 55, 41, 24, 16, 9, 1]
```

my attempt:

```js
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  var percentage = Math.floor(nums[i] / 100);
  results.push(percentage).toFixed(2);
}

document.write(results.join(", "));
```

Comment: your result will be come if you devide 1000 instead of 100.

Comment: This is similar to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159297/limiting-large-numbers) you just asked earlier on this site.

Comment: @Zeeshan is right here, you need to devide by 1000. "Array to percentages" of what like, sum of all array element or out of a constant value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Bitwise OR (`|`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR).

```
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];

var convertToPercentages = function (arr, max) {
    return nums.map(function (d, i) {
        // time for some math
        // we know the max is n
        // so, to produce a whole-number percent
        // we need to divide each digit `d` by `max`,
        // then multiply by 100
        // we then (`| 0`) to remove the decimals (same as Math.floor)
        return (100 * d / max) | 0;
    });
}
```

**better method (determines its own max)**:

```
var getNearestPowerOfTen = function (arr) {
    var max = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
        // is the previous less than the current item?
        // if so, then return the current item
        // otherwise, return the previous item
        return p < c ? c : p;
    }, 0);
    // to find the next highest power of 10,
    // we should return 10 raised to the number of digits
    // in the integer part of our number
    return Math.pow(10, (max | 0).toString().length);
}

var convertToPercentages2 = function (arr) {
    var max = getNearestPowerOfTen(arr);
    return nums.map(function (d, i) {
        return (100 * d / max) | 0;
        // could be more efficient with just
        // `(d / max) | 0`, if you divide `max` by 100 above
    });
}
```

**even better method (since we're doing math anyway)**

```
var getNearestPowerOfTen2 = function (arr) {
    var max = arr[0];
    // for-loop is faster than `Array.prototype.reduce`
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
    }
    return Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(max)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];
var results = [];


for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  var divideBy = 0;
  if ( nums[i] < 10000 )
     divideBy = 100;
  else if ( nums[i] < 100000 )
     divideBy = 1000;
  else if ( nums[i] < 1000000 )
     divideBy = 10000;
  else if ( nums[i] < 10000000 )
     divideBy = 100000;
  else if ( nums[i] < 100000000 )
     divideBy = 1000000;
  var percentage = Math.floor(nums[i] / divideBy);

  results.push( percentage.toFixed(2) );
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This is a very bad way to determine what to divide by. What if my number is `Math.pow(10, 9)`?

Answer (score 1):

From your question (desired results), it looks like all your numbers are 3 precision floats that have been multiplied by 1000.

If you want the results rounded based on the next sig digit:

```js
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];

function roundedPercents(n){
  return (n/1000).toFixed(0);
}
var roundedResults = nums.map(roundedPercents);
document.write(roundedResults.join(", "));
```

If you just want the first two digits:

```js
var nums = [84394, 78952, 65570, 58097, 55673, 41847, 24884, 16567, 9966, 1689];

function flooredPercents(n){
  return Math.floor(n/1000);
}
var flooredResults = nums.map(flooredPercents);
document.write(flooredResults.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

  var percentage = parseInt((nums[i] + '').slice(0,2));

  results.push( percentage );
}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some description about your solution.